# Override console.log (or any function in general): Is there a proper way to do this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, log4javascript

I find myself doing this quite often both on the browser and in node.js and it's about time I came up with a proper way to do this without debugging it for a while each time.

Here's what I'm currently working on (this is node.js):

```
var log4js = require("log4js");

log4js.loadAppender('file');
log4js.addAppender(log4js.appenders.file('log.log'));
var logger = log4js.getLogger();
console.log = function () {
    logger.debug.apply(logger, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
};
```

This is basically a monkey patch to take `console.log`ging code and turn it into proper logging code.

*I'm not sure if this is something proper or completely asinine.*

Conceptually, I am forcing arguments sent to console.log into an array, which then is passed to `apply`. All of this is to work around the fact that I don't know how to declare a variadic function in JS. (perhaps this is the canonical way to do so).

Perhaps the same can be achieved with `console.log = logger.debug`. Oh well, I want to know how I can pass the arguments.

For instance, there are certain things of this sort that won't work for whatever reason in the browser (but does in node):

```
var l = console.log;
l('hello');
```

[image]

Granted, this is not the same as overriding console.log, this is just to shorten the name of it, but still.

Ah, I actually realized what's wrong here: This will work.

```
l.call(console, 'hello');
```

Which means it's just missing a bit of finagling with `this`.

If you are still looking for the actual question of this question look at the italicized line above.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not sure if this is something proper or completely asinine.

For your own projects, it should be fine. Though, I would probably refrain from modifying Node's documented API (beyond the few parts that suggest modification) for any projects you intend to distribute on NPM.

---

Currently, `.apply()` is the only way to specify a collection as the arguments to a function call.

```
logger.debug.apply(logger, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
```

Though, ECMAScript 6 will be introducing the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Spread_operator) as an alternative.

```
logger.debug(...arguments);
```

However, the `slice` probably isn't necessary, since it isn't modifying the collection before passing it.

```
logger.debug.apply(logger, arguments);
```

---

As for `l('hello')`, you can use `.bind()` to ensure the context.

```
var l = console.log.bind(console);
l('hello');
```

Though, this does depend on what version of a particular engine you're using. With Node 0.10.15 and Chrome 28, `console.log` is already bound to `console`. So, the snippet you listed wouldn't throw an error.