# Is there any real danger to overriding the default 'console' in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a habit driven creature, and console.log/console.error/etc happens to be the thing I just instinctively use to print things out. However, I'm trying to drive all my logging in node to 'winston'. I'd prefer to do something like `var console = require('./modules/logger');` at the top of my file and then just use console.whatever as usual.. tapping into extra arguments as necessary (otherwise the api is pretty much the same). Since this is localized to the file I'm working with and not some sort of global change, is there any danger in setting 'console' to that module's export? And not just "well, it might be confusing for someone else".

I did notice [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050744/override-console-log-or-any-function-in-general-is-there-a-proper-way-to-do-t) pop up as a similar question, but it doesn't really answer whether there's a danger behind it. And there's some other questions that ask if you can **override** some of node's core, but I'm not doing that - I'm just making a local reference using the same name as a "magic" global.

Answer (score 1):

Other than possibly overriding existing console functions in a non-standard (i.e. unexpected) way, I do not see any danger in replacing the global console with your own object as long as it provides all the expected functions and calling conventions (function signatures) as the default console. I've done it many times without issue.

If you do provide some non-standard implementation of an existing function on the global console with a different signature than other code expects, you're bound to run into problems.

If you do your replacement in a module or function scope, only  references in that scope would be affected.